# How to extract text with respect to the heading?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pdfminer, pdf-extraction

Actually, I am trying to extract section of pdf with respect to the heading like in the sample pdf file we select the heading `ABSTRACT` so as output we need the text from `The game` to `penalty area.` . I am trying the below code, but I am getting error. `AttributeError: 'PDFPageInterpreter' object has no attribute 'layout'`.
so can someone please guide me how fix this error.

```
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from io import StringIO

def extract_text_under_heading(pdf_file, heading):
    output_string = StringIO()
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, output_string, laparams=LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)

    text = ""
    next_heading = None
    found_heading = False

    with open(pdf_file, 'rb') as file, StringIO() as output:
        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(file, check_extractable=True):
            interpreter.process_page(page)
            for element in interpreter.layout:
                if isinstance(element, LTTextBox):
                    if heading in element.get_text() and not found_heading:
                        found_heading = True
                        text += element.get_text()
                    elif found_heading:
                        text += element.get_text()
                        for h in headings:
                            if h in element.get_text():
                                next_heading = h
                                break
                        if next_heading:
                            break
    return text
```

Below is the error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [3], line 1
----> 1 extract_text_under_heading(file, 'ABSTRACT')

Cell In [2], line 20, in extract_text_under_heading(pdf_file, heading)
     18 for page in PDFPage.get_pages(file, check_extractable=True):
     19     interpreter.process_page(page)
---> 20     for element in interpreter.layout:
     21         if isinstance(element, LTTextBox):
     22             if heading in element.get_text() and not found_heading:

AttributeError: 'PDFPageInterpreter' object has no attribute 'layout'
```

Thank you in advance.

[Path to the file](https://github.com/Laxmi530/General_Doc/blob/main/Sample_PDF_file.pdf)

Comment: Your file doesn’t seem to have a table of contents in the metadata.

Comment: @kirjosieppo That is just a sample file created from a word file, so you might not get the metadata.

Comment: See the [`.extract_pages()` example.](https://pdfminersix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/extract_pages.html#extract-elements-from-a-pdf-using-python) for the updated way to do this.

Comment: @jqurious Thanks for the comment. Already i tried this but it is giving me character wise font name and font size so again i need to apply some complex logic to get line wise font name and font size, i need at least line wise font name and font size so that i can do this.

Comment: Hm, ok. But it works on your sample? Or am I not understanding correctly? Have you also tried [pdfplumber?](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber) Its `.extract_words()` method can report fontname/sizes e.g. `page.extract_words(extra_attrs=["fontname", "size"])`

Comment: @jqurious Yes already I tried with [pdfplumber](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber/discussions/797) but not getting the proper solution using pdfplumber. You can do one thing just change the portrait pdf to landscape pdf and see the output that is totally different in pdfplumber.

Comment: @KJ Thanks for the comment and let me try pdftotext and will update you.